# Issue with scheduling 4 subsequent local notification in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications, uilocalnotification

I'm trying to create 4 different local notifications that are separated by a static time difference. Means, the first notification will fire at the start time and then each X seconds another local notification will fire ( 4 total).

The problem that only 2 local notifcaiotns are creates and not 4 . I have no idea why.

```objc
double timeToAdd=0;

double timeDifference=[album.end_time timeIntervalSinceDate:album.start_time]/4;
for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
{
   NSDate *dateToNotify = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:timeToAdd sinceDate:album.start_time];

   UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
   localNotification.fireDate = dateToNotify;
   localNotification.alertBody = @"Click to sync";
   localNotification.alertAction=@"Click to sync";
   localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
   localNotification.userInfo =@{@"id":[ album.id stringByAppendingString:album.code]};
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
   timeToAdd+=timeDifference;
}
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me, 4 notifications are created and eventually delivered. Try to log notification fireDate prior to `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];` and post the result here. `NSLog(@"%@", localNotification.fireDate.description);`

Comment: What's the gap between each local notification?

Comment: It always creates just the second notification and the forth.

Comment: Aviv, we need exact time values. I'm sure that all of these notifications **are created**, yet not all **fire** at the appropriate time. We can't help you without this information.

Comment: For example , the first date is 2014-08-16 06:24:24 +0000
 , the second is 2014-08-17 18:24:24 +0000
, third 2014-08-20 18:24:24 +0000 and forth 2014-08-22 06:24:24 +0000
.

Comment: After I create them , i added a line of code just for check if they were created :   
 NSArray *eventArray = [app scheduledLocalNotifications];
...
In this array , it's only showing me that 2 notifications were created

Comment: Thx all, it's probably just didn't shown me the notifications in the array.
When i connect my phone , all 4 notification are firing.